# How to run proxy for react/redux application on AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, yaml, aws-amplify

I have recently Implemented **Proxy** (in Express.js) for my **React App** to hide API URL's when making a request. It has been working perfectly fine when I run it the proxy and app on localhost. Now that I'm ready to deploy My application to ***AWS Amplify***, I am a little confused as to how I get my proxy to run there since I'm not manually starting the app and proxy from the CLI. Do I need to use an **EC2 instance** instead or can I achieve this using **Amplify**?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

**This is what my Project Directory Looks like :**

[image: Project Directory]

**This is what my Server.js looks like :**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express(); 
const axios = require('axios');
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));

const BASE_URL = 'https://my-aws-lambda-base-url/dev'
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; 


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)); 

  app.use('/contact', require('body-parser').json(), async (req, res) => {
  
    
    try {
      
      await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/contact`, {

              Email : req.body.Email,
              type :  req.body.type,
              Message : req.body.Message,
              Phone : req.body.Phone    
          },
           {
            headers: {
                
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        },
          
          ).then(function(response) { 
    
      const result = response.data

      console.log(result)
      if(result && result.Message)  {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
      }
      
  }).catch((e)=> {
  
            console.log(e)  
    res.send(false)
         
  })
} catch (error) {
     
  console.log(error)
  res.send(false)
}
 });
```

**And this is how I make the request from In my React App**

```
export  async function sendContact(request){

    try {
        

        if(!request.Phone)
            request.Phone = false

        if(request.textMe){
            request.type = "BOTH"
        }
        else{
            request.type = "EMAIL"
        }    
            let result ;
           await fetch('/contact', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                    Email : request.Email,
                    type : request.type,
                    Message : request.Message,
                    Phone : request.Phone
                 }) 
                }
                
                ).then(async response => 
                    await response.json()
                ).then(data => 
                         result = data 
                ).catch((e)=> { 
                    notifyError(e.response.data.Message) 
                    return false           
                })
        console.log(result)
    return result

} catch (error) {
        
    console.log(error)
}
              
}
```

**And Finally, Here's My Build Script from Amplify for my application**

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm i
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

**P.S : I do also have `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` added to my Package.json**

**EDIT  :**

I tried Using a Background task manager like [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to run post build in the build script but that still did not work (although it did locally)

Comment: your requirement sounds very much like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996486/setting-up-proxy-for-express-react-on-aws-amplify the answer is downvoted but seems fine

Comment: Is `/contact` the only endpoint you have on your server?

Comment: @ale917k no I actually have multiple, one to Authenticate access to Admin panel (return JWT) via digital signature using metamask. Also another one for the admin to fetch all messages, and finally one to reply to messages

Comment: @diedu Sadly, I do not quite understand how i could use that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up spinning up a proxy lambda as my API gateway (middle man) between my client and server. I also have the proxy denying any requests not coming from my website.